# Restructuring JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
  "App 1": "5a67-b-45-86e7-bfb351",
  "App 2": "293-e2-4a-96c-4471d0ea",
  "App 3": "f87d5-e0-41-bd-16dc72e"
}
```

I would like it to be reconstructed in the following JSON format using Python:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "5a67-b-45-86e7-bfb351",
    "name" : "App 1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "293-e2-4a-96c-4471d0ea",
    "name" : "App 2"
  },
  {
    "id":"f87d5-e0-41-bd-16dc72e",
    "name":"App 3"
  }
]
```

Comment: It's traditional to offer some sort of attempt yourself when asking. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @PaulRooney yes SO is not a code writing service. It is my bad that I did not mention the previous approaches that I tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of similar questions out there.  I would just use list comprehension:

```
[{'id': value, 'name': key} for key, value in original.items()]
```

If it is JSON, not a python object, it's easy to load/dump it:

```
import json
...
original = json.loads(json_string)
modified = [{'id': value, 'name': key} for key, value in original.items()]
output = json.dumps(modified) # New JSON string
```

Comment: Suggested edit: you've actually used a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)! Which makes sense, since the result is a list. ;)